# Why ajax post not work when using file name on base tag?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Why ajax post not work when using 
`url: 'filename.php',` on

`<base href="//example.com">` ?

This is my ajax post code.

```
<script>
function send_username_value_for_check_available() {
        $.ajax({
                url: 'test.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: $('#username_send_value_fid').serialize(),
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#mySpan_username').show();
                    $('#mySpan_username').html(data);
                }
            });
}
</script>
```

it's not working, it's show error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://example.com/test.php. Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)
```

But when i remove

```
<base href="//example.com">
```

from `<head></head>`

my ajax post will work good ^_^

I want to know how to use ajax post `url: 'filename.php',` on `<base href="//example.com">` ?

.

.

.

```
remark : my site using ssl https.
```

Comment: headers: {
      'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
   },

Try to add this header to define the content type

Comment: Try adding `https` before the url if you don't want to do so make sure loaded page is loaded at `https`;